# How to give a specific user, ftp access to multiple directories?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, plesk

I have a plesk panel and  want to give ftp access to a user. I want this user to access multiple folders within `htdocs` directory, without creating multiple ftp accounts!  How should I do that?

I have searched a lot and it seems there is no way to do this :(

I have ssh access too, if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can create fake root folder and bind folders(or ask tech support) inside it

```
~ mkdir httpdocs/fakeroot
~ mkdir httpdocs/fakeroot/folder1
~ mkdir httpdocs/fakeroot/folder2
# mount --bind httpdocs/folder1 httpdocs/fakeroot/folder1
# mount --bind httpdocs/folder1 httpdocs/fakeroot/folder1
```

Unfortunately only root can `mount` with `bind`

Than create additional FTP account with access to `httpdocs/fakeroot`